# How to query and display layer using ArcGIS Python script tool?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, tools, arcpy

I have database which contains point shapefiles and raster files for 3 species.
My aim is to develop a script tool that should have a search tab to enter the species name.
also, a check box to select what layers to display.
how to develop this.

give me hint to develop python script for querying and display a layer.
also, i should add the script tool as a button in the toolbar.

Comment: This Question looks like it has three "questions": 1) "script tool that should have a search tab to enter the species name"; 2) "check box to select what layers to display"; and 3) "add the script tool as a button in the toolbar".  I recommend that you edit your question to focus it on the most important of these to you, and then to research/ask the others separately.

Answer (score 2):

Using a script tool, you could allow the user to define the search layer, and what additional layers to add to your map.  The script flow would look something like this:

1. user defines layer to search against within the script tool interface
2. user defines layer(s) to add into map document using the [AddLayer (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000025000000) method
3. next a [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000050000000) is used to search for the entered species name (entered with a text box within the script tool)

I'm not sure what the result of your query should do (e.g. zoom to feature, only show queried features?)?

Comment: Thank u.. Result of a query is only to display the queried features.

Comment: and, how can i add check boxes.. like the aim is too display the accession locations of the species(point shapefile), and two raster layers exhibiting their potential distribution. the user needs to specify as which layer the wants too add in the TOC.